# How do I get ubuntu desktop running on my virtual box CLI? It's stuck "Loading extension GLX"

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, desktop-environments

I've got a vmware virtualbox with Ubuntu 14.04 CLI installed. I'm now trying to get `ubuntu-desktop` GUI running. I've already installed `ubuntu-desktop` with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. I read elsewhere on this forum that I should then run `sudo startx` However, when I do that, it seems to get stuck on `Loading extension GLX`. So... what do?

The full thing looks like this:

```
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
```

Also, `lspci` reveals:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX AGP bridge (rev 01)
00:07.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 08)
00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:07.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:07.7 System peripheral: VMware Virtual Machine Communication Interface (rev 10)
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
00:11.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI bridge (rev 02)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 USB
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
02:02.0 USB controller: VMware USB2 EHCI Controller
```

/var/log/Xorg.2.log ends with:

```
[ 58763.975] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[ 58763.975] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 58763.975] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 58763.975] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse (/dev/input/event2)
[ 58763.975] (**) ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[ 58763.975] (**) ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse: Applying InputClass "vmmouse"
[ 58763.975] (II) LoadModule: "vmmouse"
[ 58763.975] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/vmmouse_drv.so
[ 58763.976] (II) Module vmmouse: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 58763.976]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 13.0.0
[ 58763.976]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[ 58763.976]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[ 58763.976] (II) VMWARE(0): VMMOUSE module was loaded
[ 58763.976] (II) Using input driver 'vmmouse' for 'ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse'
[ 58763.976] (**) ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse: always reports core events
[ 58763.976] (II) VMWARE(0): vmmouse is available
[ 58763.976] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[ 58763.988] (**) ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse: ZAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[ 58763.988] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3/event2"
[ 58763.988] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[ 58763.988] (II) VMWARE(0): VMMOUSE DEVICE_INIT
[ 58763.988] (**) ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[ 58763.988] (**) ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[ 58763.988] (**) ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 58763.988] (**) ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[ 58763.988] (II) VMWARE(0): VMMOUSE DEVICE_ON
[ 58763.988] (II) VMWARE(0): vmmouse enabled
[ 58763.988] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[ 58763.988] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 58763.988] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 58764.457] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 58764.761] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 58764.774] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 58772.180] (II) VMWARE(0): VMMOUSE DEVICE_OFF/CLOSE
[ 58772.512] (II) VMWARE(0): VMMOUSE DEVICE_OFF/CLOSE
[ 58772.812] (II) VMWARE(0): VMMouseUnInit
[ 58772.813] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Close
[ 58772.813] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 58772.813] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[ 58772.813] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 58772.814] (II) vmware(0): Terminating Xv video-stream id:0
[ 58772.936] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```